# Magento 2: How to set meta tags for dynamic pages custom module in Controller, Block or .phtml?

Tags: magento2, module, custom, magento-2.1.7

I have created a custom module with admin grid form where data is entered and saved in database then it I retrieve to display at frontend.
So as an e.g  I have followed for the frontend part this blog post [toptal](https://www.toptal.com/magento/magento-2-tutorial-building-a-complete-module) after success implementation I have individual pages like so: http://magento2.dev/blog/post/view/id/1, ../id/2, and so on...

All of the meta tags are being recorded in database and I need to be able to add this for example in my Controller:

```
public function execute()
{
    $post = $this->_post->create();
    $this->_coreRegistry->register(self::REGISTRY_KEY_STORE_ID, (int) $this->_request->getParam('id'));
    $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();

    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set($post->getMetaTitle());
    $resultPage->getConfig()->setDescription($post->getMetaDescription());
    $resultPage->getConfig()->setKeywords($post->getMetaKeywords());

    return $resultPage;
}
```

Where

> $post->getMetaTitle(), $post->getMetaDescription() and
>   $post->getMetaKeywords()

are my functions from model Post that extends PostInterface.

But I had no luck when I `var_dump($post->getMetaTitle())` I get `NULL`

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've finally Cracked it, in my Controller. after Injecting postFactory I retrieve data like this:

```
public function execute() {



    $post = $this->_postFactory->create();
    //Load single post by id 
    $data = $post->load($this->_request->getParam('id'));
    // OR load entire collection
    //$collection = $post->getCollection(); 
    //print_r($collection->getData());

    $this->_coreRegistry->register(self::REGISTRY_KEY_STORE_ID, (int) 
    $this->_request->getParam('id'));
    $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();

    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set($data->getData()['meta_title']);
    $resultPage->getConfig()->setDescription($data->getData()['meta_description']);
    $resultPage->getConfig()->setKeywords($data->getData()['meta_keywords']);

    return $resultPage;

}
```

This worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

From Block class, you can set Meta Title, Description and Keywords as below:

```
public function __construct(
    ---
    \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config $pageConfig,
    ---
) {
    ---
    $this->_pageConfig = $pageConfig;   
    ---
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

 /**
 * Prepare global layout
 *
 * @return $this
 */
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    if($this->getSeoTitle())
        $this->_pageConfig->getTitle()->set('Meta Title');

    if($this->getMetaKeywords())        
        $this->_pageConfig->setKeywords('Meta Keywords');

    if($this->getMetaDescription())         
        $this->_pageConfig->setDescription('Meta Description');

    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

Comment: you have **'Meta Title'**  hard coded but it needs to be dynamic, that means it needs to come from one of the function I have set that retrieves from database  of the corresponding post id

Comment: Yes here you can create one function that will fetch currently loaded post and assign data here

Comment: Thanks , Do you have an example function to retrieve currently loaded post data here -

Comment: You can check here in `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View` Product View block

Comment: This is very helpful for someone who doesn't know that the \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config object has been injected into block for FREE during construction (like me) and dubbed $this->pageConfig.